# Transport options between Vilanculos and Inhambane

Tags: transportation, mozambique

I found there is only flight a day between the two, and since that flight is fully booked for my dates, I am looking for another way to travel between the two cities.

What my other transport options between the two cities?

Comment: Yes, but it seems like such a long trip around for 4h driving. Plus tickets are not so cheap.

Comment: FWIW, I did the Inhambane to Vilanculos trip by public transport a bunch of years ago. I'm convinced this is still an option, as it would be in the opposite direction. But, expect this to be slow and uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transport options are normally air, rail, road or sea. For air there are alternative, though indirect, routes (eg via Maputo or J'burg). [Rail](http://www.seat61.com/Mozambique.htm) seems out of the question. By road there is public transport, but slow, complicated and uncomfortable, or taxi. By sea could be slow and expensive and would require negotiation since there is no ferry link. I take it on foot does not count as a transportation option.